# Remove Username Field on Woocommerce Registration Page?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to remove Username Field on Woocommerce Registration Page, how do I do that? Or How do I use user email as username, or make the username field not required? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Follow below steps properly.

Step-1: Remove Username textfield

```
 add_action('login_head', function(){
?>
    <style>
        #registerform > p:first-child{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#registerform > p:first-child').css('display', 'none');
        });
    </script>
<?php
});
```

Step-2: Remove Username error

```
//Remove error for username, only show error for email only.
add_filter('registration_errors', function($wp_error, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email){
    if(isset($wp_error->errors['empty_username'])){
        unset($wp_error->errors['empty_username']);
    }

    if(isset($wp_error->errors['username_exists'])){
        unset($wp_error->errors['username_exists']);
    }
    return $wp_error;
}, 10, 3);
```

Step-3: Manipulate Background Registration Functionality.

```
add_action('login_form_register', function(){
    if(isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email'])){
        $_POST['user_login'] = $_POST['user_email'];
    }
});
```

Put above code in your theme's functions.php file.